# Any way to load user specified https page inside popup.html of browser extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xss, firefox-addon-webextensions, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, browser-extension

I'd like to have users authenticate into a service from within my popup.html browser extension, but the url for the service they use can't be predefined (e.g. different servers are at different URLs) and the authentication must be over HTTPS. Currently they enter the url of their server and I open a new window, monitor the url, and grab the Auth key from the url and close the tab, But I'd prefer to just load the mobile view of the site inside the extension for a more seamless experience.

My understanding is that this may not be possible due to xss and previous ways of using an iframe to do this will no longer be approved by Google/Mozilla.

Any workaround?

Comment: An iframe (or a new tab/window) is the only way.

Comment: Adding to @wOxxOm: Be aware of cross-domain and/or preflight on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your Chrome extension Manifest V3:

**manifest.json** file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "__MSG_name__",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "__MSG_description__",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "24": "icons/icon24.png",
    "32": "icons/icon32.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "96": "icons/icon96.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "action": {
    "default_title": "__MSG_pageatitle__",
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icons/icon19.png",
      "38": "icons/icon38.png"
    }
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "default-src 'none'; style-src 'self'; child-src https://www.youtube.com; script-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; object-src 'none'"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs"],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

**popup.html** file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="login" title="Login box" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SlGuvC5nnTA" width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no">Your browser does not support iframes.</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**Signing in users**

If you want to use the Signing in users from a Chrome extension, see this Google Cloud documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/chrome-extension
Note: This currently only works in the Chrome extension Manifest V2. And not in the latest Chrome extension Manifest V3 technology.

Comment: I’m not sure how this will work for a dynamic, user provided urls after install though? I understand how to hardcode a specific url into opening in the iframe, but not an end-user provide one after install. And what would the code looks like because the “openness” of any user input is what I’m worried about for the extension security approval.